# How to make a block visible on a particular page and as well as on taxonomy term page?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, blocks

here is my situation,

I have a Taxonomy menu block built using taxonomy_menu and taxonomy_menu_trails module. And I have used block_term module to display the menu on nodes with given term(s).

Now, how can I display the same taxonomy menu block on taxonomy term pages as well?

I tried adding the taxonomy term page link to display block only the listed pages. but it did not work. while doing this I had both the conditions (Display on nodes that are taged to terms and Show only on listed pages) checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this issue is solved using the Context module with Omega theme. (Without need of editing template files)

Step 1: As i mentioned in the question use taxonomy_menu and taxonomy_menu_trails module with block_term module to display the menu on nodes with given term(s).
[Now the blocks are displayed only on the nodes tagged to particular term(s)]

Step 2: Using Context add a new context

Step 3: Add a condition as: Taxonomy Term, and select the respective terms where you need the taxonomy block to be displayed.

Step 4: Add a Reaction > Blocks

Step 5: On the right hand side list of blocks are displayed with check boxes. Select the block that you need to show

Step 6: in the middle column all the regions are listed with a [+Add] button. Click on [+Add] button and save the context.

Therefor, now the block(s) is displayed on nodes as well as on the taxonomy term pages too.

Answer (score 1):

Well from what I understood from your question, you can use following lines of code in your template file where you want to display the block:

```
if(arg(0) == 'taxonomy' && arg(1) == 'term') {
  $tid = (int)arg(2);
  $term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
  $taxo_term = $term->vocabulary_machine_name;

  if ($taxo_term == "your_vocabulary_name") {
    print render($page['your_block_region']);
  }
}
```

PS: I dont know if this is very standard(drupal) way to achieve this but it has        worked for me.

Comment: i think better to check taxonomy term like this -> `if (arg(0) == 'taxonomy' && arg(1) == 'term' && is_numeric(arg(2))) {`

Comment: Thanks @sandesh yadav and #neok, for the quick response.

Comment: I am currently using omega theme with context module and I am not sure if I can edit template.php file

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to mention that this issue is for Drupal 7

Comment: @AnAnD you can put it on page.tpl.php wherever you want the block to be displayed. :)

Comment: @sandeshyadav in D7 while using Omega theme with Delta and Context I cannot use page.tpl.php